# Convert a colon separated string to a list - within a list of dictionaries... (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, split

I have data coming from a database which returns a list of dictionaries that look something like this:

```
products = [{'product': 'car', 'colour': 'blue', 'properties': 'stereo;aircon;magwheels'},
            {'product': 'bus', 'colour': 'red', 'properties': 'microphone;aircon;dvd'},
            {'product': 'motorbike', 'colour': 'black', 'properties': None}]
```

Before it gets passed on for use within the application, I would like to convert the colon separated strings to a list, so the result would be this:

```
[{'product': 'car', 'colour': 'blue', 'properties': ['stereo', 'aircon', 'magwheels']},
 {'product': 'bus', 'colour': 'red', 'properties': ['microphone', 'aircon', 'dvd']},
 {'product': 'motorbike', 'colour': 'black', 'properties': None}]
```

I am currently doing it by iterating over all of items in the list, and applying the following logic:

```
for product in products:
    if product['properties'] is not None:
        product['properties'] = product['properties'].split(';')
```

I have to do this for 5 keys within the dictionary, so essentially I am repeating this logic 5 times, once for each key, like so:

```
for product in products:
    if product['properties'] is not None:
        product['properties'] = product['properties'].split(';')
    if product['blah'] is not None:
        product['blah'] = product['blah'].split(';')
    if product['foo'] is not None:
        product['foo'] = product['foo'].split(';')
```

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: To clarify, the keys that need this processing are a known set. I can't run the split on all keys, as there is a risk that a ; could legitimately exist for those keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance the keys for which you have to split the dictionary value, you can store these keys, as strings, in a `set`:

```
ok2split = set('properties', 'foo', 'blah')
```

then you can do the conversion as follows

```
new = [{k:(d[k].split(';')if(d[k] and k in ok2split)else d[k])for k in d}for d in products]
```

or, operating in place,

```
for d in products:
    for k in d:
        if d[k] and k in ok2split: d[k] = d[k].split(';')
```

Answer (score 0):

you try, code following, first I iterate in each dictionary, next, I use [iteritems](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) for iterate in each element of dictionary

```
products = [{'product': 'car', 'colour': 'blue', 'properties': 'stereo;aircon;magwheels'},
            {'product': 'bus', 'colour': 'red', 'properties': 'microphone;aircon;dvd'},
            {'product': 'motorbike', 'colour': 'black', 'properties': None}]

for dict_product in products:
  for key, val in dict_product.iteritems():
    if val is not None and val.find(";") != -1:
      dict_product[key] = val.split(";")
```

you get:

> [{'product': 'car', 'colour': 'blue', 'properties': ['stereo', 'aircon', 'magwheels']},
>
> {'product': 'bus', 'colour': 'red', 'properties': ['microphone', 'aircon', 'dvd']},
>
> {'product': 'motorbike', 'colour': 'black', 'properties': None}]

Comment: `dict` is a Python builtin, you'd better use another name for the current dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a dict comprehension within a list comprehension :

```
 [ { key: value and value.split(';') for key, value in product.items() } 
      for product in products ]
```

Note that since a value can be None instead of a string, you write `value and value.split(';')`, instead of just the split alone.

If you don't want the string split unless there is a semicolon to split on (seems odd to me but whatevs), you have to say so explicitly

```
 [ { key: value.split(';') 
             if value and ';' in value 
             else value
     for key, value in product.items() } 
      for product in products ]
```

You might want to break the value processing out into a function:

```
 def splitOnSemi(value):
    return (value.split(';') 
             if value and ';' in value 
             else value)

 [ { key: splitOnSemi(value)
     for key, value in product.items() } 
      for product in products ]
```